# No Knead Bread comes out a tad gummy only in the center

Tags: baking, steaming, wheat, rye

I’m using 200g Bread flour, 50g Whole Wheat flour , 50g All-purpose flour, and 60g Rye.  I add 2.25tsp of yeast, 2tsp sea salt, and 1.5cups filtered tap water.

I let it rise overnight or at least 9hrs.  I find that it has risen comp,etely, yet has started to drop by the time Im ready to bake it.

I steam it in a Dutch Oven for 30 minutes at 450, then uncover it for 40 minutes again at 450.  But it makes my loaf crust to hard on the bottom, and my knife a little sticky.  How should I tweak this??

Comment: Do you have an over thermometer?  You may want to check the temperature of your oven.  You can also use a probe thermometer to check the temperature of the bread to ensure it's done in the middle  (time isn't always reliable).  And possibly related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/97376/67

Comment: What temperature do you let it rise at? Nine hours sounds rather long, given your yeast ratio?

Comment: What do you mean by it makes your knife sticky?

Comment: Where did you get this recipe? It does not conform to the standard no knead recipe. It looks like your hydration is near 100%...the yeast and salt ratio are also quite high.

Comment: 1.5 (metric) cups is 375ml of water - this is a lot of water for 360 grams of flour(s).  We use 350ml into 500g of flour, using a similar flour mix to yours.

Comment: Oooohhhh.... you guys are way beyond me.   I do find when I am using only bread flour or all purpose flour that it is neither sticky nor too salty... the salt could be my preference, I guess.   But it’s only when I modify the original recipe of ALL WHITE FLOUR that it becomes this way.   I want a rich texture and flavor that I get from the wheat and rye.   It’s a brand new oven... but I will check my owners manual for calibration.   Anyone else??

Comment: My apologies I am using Imperial units for my water = 1-1/2 cups.  It sits on the counter for a minimum of 9 hours.  Again, I’ve adjusted the salt to my taste.  It was originally 1-1/2tsp.